# database size increased after restoring on another drive

Tags: sql-server

I have restored my database on to another drive and renamed it. I have noticed that my actual database size is 500GB where as the restored (New) went to 600GB. Any theory behind this how it happened.

Comment: Is 500GB the size of the original database or the backup? The backup doesn't contain empty data pages. As for the size difference, a cluster size difference could account for it. Apart from that one would have to guess about your hardware, server, database configuration

Comment: The size of database was 500GB mate.

Comment: Is it the same version of SQL Server?  Have you got all the same fill factors on indexes, or have they changed to new defaults somewhere - maybe there is some other type of default setting difference on what I presume is a different SQL Server installation.

Comment: @Cato: Yes mate. Restored on same version of Sql server (2008R2 Standard). No changes have been made.